# Run different MySQL query based upon URL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query that displays data from my database. Here is the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(InvoiceAmount) AS TotalBilling,SUM(ClientCostToDate) AS WIP FROM Estimates WHERE date_format(InvoiceDate, '%Y-%m')=date_format(now(), '%Y-%m')";
```

This query displays data from a MySQL database into a HTML table on my page. I need to add a small change to this `$sql` query based upon the URL. Is this possible?

Ideally, it would work something like:

If / or index.php, run this:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(InvoiceAmount) AS TotalBilling,SUM(ClientCostToDate) AS WIP FROM Estimates WHERE date_format(InvoiceDate, '%Y-%m')=date_format(now(), '%Y-%m')";
```

If /london.php, run this:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(InvoiceAmount) AS TotalBilling,SUM(ClientCostToDate) AS WIP FROM Estimates WHERE Studio = 'London' date_format(InvoiceDate, '%Y-%m')=date_format(now(), '%Y-%m')";
```

There is only a small change to the query per page - and that is to display results where `Studio = 'London'`. This is so that I can display results that only pertain to London on london.php.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Thank you for your help.

Here is my full script:

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';

// create connection
$conn = new mysqli($currentConfig['host'], $currentConfig['user'],             $currentConfig['pass'], $currentConfig['name']);
// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die('Connection failed: '.$conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT SUM(InvoiceAmount) AS TotalBilling,SUM(ClientCostToDate) AS WIP FROM Estimates WHERE date_format(InvoiceDate, '%Y-%m')=date_format(now(), '%Y-%m') AND Studio = 'Splash London'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $wip = $row['WIP'];
  $total_billing = $row['TotalBilling'];

  // US national money format
  setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');

  // echo data into HTML table
  echo
  '<tbody>'.'<tr>'.'<td>'. money_format('%(#10n',$total_billing) . "\n" .'</td>'.'<td>'. money_format('%(#10n',$wip) . "\n" .'</td>';
  }
} else {
echo 'No results';
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Just make a if statement

Answer (score 3):

Yes well this is kind of the most basic type of thing that you can do with a serverside script.

First off you don't require multiple scripts.  The index.php will do fine.

Add a parameter of studio.

So optionally you would use either:

```
http://../index.php
```

or

```
http://..index.php?studio=london
```

It should be obvious at this point that the advantage of this is that when you have other studios in the database other than london, this code still works.

At the top of your script:

```
if (isset($_GET['studio']) {
   $studio = $_GET['studio'];
} else {
   $studio = '';
}
```

Now you can run a different query based on the whether or not there was a url parameter passed.

```
if ($studio == '') {
   // $sql = ...
} else {
   $sql = "SELECT SUM(InvoiceAmount) AS TotalBilling,SUM(ClientCostToDate) AS WIP FROM Estimates WHERE Studio = '$studio' date_format(InvoiceDate, '%Y-%m')=date_format(now(), '%Y-%m')"; 
}
```

So, perfunctory remarks -- this code can easily be sql injected.  The specifics of how you do queries depends on the client library you are using.  You should be using either mysqli or PDO and parameter binding instead of putting a variable into the string, and then binding that variable.

For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(InvoiceAmount) AS TotalBilling,SUM(ClientCostToDate) AS WIP FROM Estimates WHERE Studio = :studio date_format(InvoiceDate, '%Y-%m')=date_format(now(), '%Y-%m')";
```

Take a look at the appropriate manual entries for mysqli or PDO for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

For example, if you full link is: http://www.mypage.com/index.php

`$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]` has "www.mypage.com"

`$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` has "/index.php"

So you can do:

```
if($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] == "/london.php"){
  $sql = "SELECT SUM(InvoiceAmount) AS TotalBilling,SUM(ClientCostToDate) AS WIP FROM Estimates WHERE Studio = 'London' date_format(InvoiceDate, '%Y-%m')=date_format(now(), '%Y-%m')";
}
else{
  $sql = "SELECT SUM(InvoiceAmount) AS TotalBilling,SUM(ClientCostToDate) AS WIP FROM Estimates WHERE date_format(InvoiceDate, '%Y-%m')=date_format(now(), '%Y-%m')";
}
```

Comment: This would work, but it still requires him to have multiple files (one for each city). In the interest of DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), gview's answer is better.

Comment: @BrianSchroeter I totally agree actually. I just gave the "obvious and direct solution" in case OP was just looking for something like this. But gview's answer is the right one.